# javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: Could not send Message - at JaxWsClientProxy.invoke - caused by HTTP response code: 401 for URL

Tags: soap, jax-ws, cxf

I moved a working code from dev to test and encountered the following error(s) in test:

```
javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: Could not send Message.
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:143)
......
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:64)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:236)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:472)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:302)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:254)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:73)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:123)
    at $Proxy739.copyIntoItems(Unknown Source)

Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: http://<sharepointportal>/_vti_bin/Copy.asmx
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1436)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:379)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponseInternal(HTTPConduit.java:2046)
```

### Environment specs:

Java 1.6
Tomcat 6
Eclipse Helios
Maven2
CXF 2.2.3

As a background work, tried to explore about the error in similar category

1. bad URL (ruled out as i am using same URL in dev and test. and the url, userid, password are all accessible from both the machines),
2. connection timeout( error is not 404 or it doesnt specify connection timed out... it says 401 response code for url)
3. Checked if all the jars and same versions are included in the test environment.

Can someone shed some light to understand and resolve the error?

please let me know if any more details are to be included.

Answer (score 1):

401 is an authentication error.

Authentication fails either at the destination URL `http:///_vti_bin/Copy.asmx` (3 slashes ?) or on a forward proxy on the way.

Are you connecting to _vti_bin via a proxy in test ?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the quick response. I am creating a JaxWsProxyFactoryBean for the address (3 slashes is just typo ... its actually http://ourportal.com.au/_vti_bin/Copy.asmx) and setting its authentication using HTTPConduit. This is the same code that's used in dev. I verified the URL and the credentials work from test machine as well.

Comment: I am talking of an Internet Proxy. Easiest way to verify where the authentication issue lies is to get the HTTP headers of the request and those of the response. Since CXF is using Sun's HttpUrlConnection, there is unfortunately not much you will be able to do with logging on the client; so you will have to get hold of an Http Sniffer or TCP packet sniffer

Comment: I am also facing same issue....working through proxy but not working without proxy....Getting connection reset exception